# Setting up allegro5 with visual studio 2012 on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, allegro5

I followed the steps on the [reference manual](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5) and when I run my project I get errors about files not being found.

Here's what I did.

1. I downloaded the bin for MSVC 11.
2. extracted it to `C:\allegro` (bin include and lib directories are inside)
3. in a new a project under properties I followed their directions replacing 5.0.x with 5.0.8

their directions are as follows:

Under Configuration Properties->C/C++->General, enter
`c:\allegro\include` in Additional Include Directories.

Under Configuration Properties->Linker->General, enter `c:\allegro\lib`
in Additional Library Directories.

Under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, append
allegro-5.0.x-monolith-md-debug.lib to Additional Dependencies.

Under Configuration Properties->Debugging, enter
`PATH=c:\allegro\bin;%PATH%` in Environment.

perhaps I appended the wrong file or didn't do it correctly?

**Properties->Linker->Input Additional Dependencies**
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies);allegro-5.0.8-monolith-md-debug.lib

The code sample they have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
 
   if(!al_init()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }
 
   display = al_create_display(640, 480);
   if(!display) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }
 
   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
 
   al_flip_display();
 
   al_rest(10.0);
 
   al_destroy_display(display);
 
   return 0;
}
```

and the errors it generates:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file
or directory    c:\users\robert\documents\visual studio
2012\projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    1   1   allegro-01
    2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"io.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\platform\almsvc.h   19  1   allegro-01
    3   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"fcntl.h"   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\platform\almsvc.h   20  1   allegro-01
    4   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"direct.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\platform\almsvc.h   21  1   allegro-01
    5   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"malloc.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\platform\almsvc.h   22  1   allegro-01
    6   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"stdint.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\platform\astdint.h  30  4   allegro-01
    7   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"errno.h"   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  23  4   allegro-01
    8   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"limits.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  29  7   allegro-01
    9   IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"stdarg.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  34  4   allegro-01
    10  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"stddef.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  35  4   allegro-01
    11  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"stdlib.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  36  4   allegro-01
    12  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"time.h"    c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  37  4   allegro-01
    13  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"string.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  38  4   allegro-01
    14  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"sys/types.h"   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  39  4   allegro-01
    15  IntelliSense: identifier "uint32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\base.h  77  1   allegro-01
    16  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  57  1   allegro-01
    17  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  58  1   allegro-01
    18  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  59  1   allegro-01
    19  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  66  1   allegro-01
    20  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  71  1   allegro-01
    21  IntelliSense: identifier "va_list" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  74  1   allegro-01
    22  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  93  1   allegro-01
    23  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  98  1   allegro-01
    24  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  100 1   allegro-01
    25  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  134 1   allegro-01
    26  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  135 1   allegro-01
    27  IntelliSense: variable "al_ustr_new_from_utf16" may not be
initialized c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  138 1   allegro-01
    28  IntelliSense: identifier "uint16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  140 1   allegro-01
    29  IntelliSense: identifier "uint16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\utf8.h  142 1   allegro-01
    30  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  55  1   allegro-01
    31  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  56  1   allegro-01
    32  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  61  1   allegro-01
    33  IntelliSense: identifier "int16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  66  1   allegro-01
    34  IntelliSense: identifier "int16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  67  1   allegro-01
    35  IntelliSense: identifier "int16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  68  1   allegro-01
    36  IntelliSense: identifier "int16_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  69  1   allegro-01
    37  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  70  1   allegro-01
    38  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  71  1   allegro-01
    39  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  72  1   allegro-01
    40  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\file.h  73  1   allegro-01
    41  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"assert.h"  c:\allegro\include\allegro5\debug.h 22  1   allegro-01
    42  IntelliSense: identifier "intptr_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\events.h    206 1   allegro-01
    43  IntelliSense: identifier "intptr_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\events.h    207 1   allegro-01
    44  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\timer.h 55  1   allegro-01
    45  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\timer.h 56  1   allegro-01
    46  IntelliSense: identifier "int64_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\timer.h 57  1   allegro-01
    47  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
"sys/types.h"   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    23  4   allegro-01
    48  IntelliSense: identifier "uint32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    96  1   allegro-01
    49  IntelliSense: identifier "time_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    97  1   allegro-01
    50  IntelliSense: identifier "time_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    98  1   allegro-01
    51  IntelliSense: identifier "time_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    99  1   allegro-01
    52  IntelliSense: identifier "off_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fshook.h    100 1   allegro-01
    53  IntelliSense: identifier "int32_t" is
undefined   c:\allegro\include\allegro5\fixed.h 30  9   allegro-01
    54  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "string.h"    c:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\guiddef.h 146 1   allegro-01
    55  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "ctype.h" c:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h   31  1   allegro-01
    56  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "excpt.h" c:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h   1240    1   allegro-01
    57  IntelliSense: identifier "EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION" is
undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h 1245    1   allegro-01  58  IntelliSense: cannot
open source file "string.h" c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h 16534   1   allegro-01  59  IntelliSense:
identifier "va_list" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinBase.h   3699    14  allegro-01  60  IntelliSense:
identifier "va_list" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinBase.h   3712    14  allegro-01  61  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "stdarg.h"  c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinUser.h   51  1   allegro-01  62  IntelliSense:
identifier "va_list" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinUser.h   278 10  allegro-01  63  IntelliSense:
identifier "va_list" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinUser.h   285 10  allegro-01  64  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "excpt.h"   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\shared\rpc.h   163 1   allegro-01  65  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "stdlib.h"  c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\combaseapi.h    329 1   allegro-01  66  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "excpt.h"   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\Windows.h   160 1   allegro-01  67  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "stdarg.h"  c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.0\Include\um\Windows.h   161 1   allegro-01  68  IntelliSense:
cannot open source file "stdio.h"   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual
Studio 2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp 1   1   allegro-01
    69  IntelliSense: identifier "atexit" is
undefined   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    8   8   allegro-01
    70  IntelliSense: identifier "fprintf" is
undefined   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    9   7   allegro-01
    71  IntelliSense: identifier "stderr" is
undefined   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    9   15  allegro-01
    72  IntelliSense: identifier "fprintf" is
undefined   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    15  7   allegro-01
    73  IntelliSense: identifier "stderr" is
undefined   c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\allegro-01\allegro-01\main.cpp    15  15  allegro-01
```

Comment: Considering that it cannot find a standard include, there's something messed up with your environment. I would first make sure you can compile a standard C++ console app before trying to configure Allegro.

Comment: with this project I cant. there is something wrong with my environment or that version of allegro isn't for this version of ms visual. for now Ill use msvc 10. I believe i can make my own build but I don't know anything about doing that. do you know any tutorials on that subject for a c++ noob?